Is there a woocommerce hook that will only execute after the payment is success and redirect back to the website?
I am working on a wordpress plugin to execute a custom function only after the payment is completed successfully. But I have no idea which hook is secure and will not be bypassed by the user.
I have tried to use, but it can be trigger by client.
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_function', 10, 1);
Then, I tried to use this hook, but it being fired before the user made the payment.
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_function', 10, 1);
My current payment gateway is QFPay. Does anyone have any idea that which hook I should use? Thanks!

I ended up using woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing. Because after I checked the code of QFPay plugin, I realized that it won't make a action call to woocommerce_payment_complete.

I think you're looking for woocommerce_payment_complete hook. Check out WooCommerce API Documentation if you need more help.

You can extend the hook to woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status_<status>. Replace <status> with processing or completed.

Thanks a lot! Is there a huge difference between the two?

@SamLo yes, it will only trigger after order status changes.

I see. Is processing the default status for a order with successful payment?

@SamLo pending is the default, you can see it here, while gateway processes payment it changes order status to processing, after that it can be canceled or completed.

Thanks. But does it have anything to do with the order status that shows in the wp-admin woocommerce order? Because I think all of the orders are in processing status before I manually set it to completed. Or the order status here only refers to the payment?
